# Table stops updating when trigger enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a legacy app that works perfectly fine.  I'm trying to create a trigger to strip out rows in a table when they get inserted into the table.  The problem is, as soon as I enable to the trigger the table no longer gets updated.  The application is continuing to run fine, but I'm guessing somehow there's a reason my trigger is disabling the table from updating?  Can someone explain how to troubleshoot or what the issue might be?

**Update:** once the trigger is enabled as I said the table stops updating.  IE. I can have a trgtskrun_id of 2345678 and no more rows will load.  as soon as I stop the trigger after a brief pause rows will start inserting again but NOT at the next logical number which means rows that should be writing to the table are getting lost in the system somewhere?  When I start it back up, using the example above the next number is 2345685 so a few transactions were ultimately dropped from being written.  very weird.

For posterity here is my trigger -

```
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trig_trgtskrunUpdate]    Script Date: 15/02/2014 11:27:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_trgtskrunUpdate] ON [dbo].[trgtskrun]
   AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @HistoryType    char(1) --"I"=insert, "U"=update, "D"=delete

SET @HistoryType=NULL

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        --INSERT
        SET @HistoryType='I'
    --handle insert or update data
    INSERT INTO [Admiral_DEV].[dbo].[happycopy]
            (trgtskrun_revtype, trgtskrun_revtm, trgtskrun_id, trgtskrun_payload, trgtskrun_status,
            trgtskrun_crtdt, trgtskrun_rundt, trgtskrun_parent, trgtskrun_transaction, trgtskrun_expire, trgtskrun_data,
            trgmst_id, tskmst_id, jobmst_id, jobrun_id, nodmst_id, nodmst_target, servicemst_id, servicemst_target,
            usrmst_id)
        SELECT
            @HistoryType, GETDATE(), trgtskrun_id, trgtskrun_payload, trgtskrun_status,
            trgtskrun_crtdt, trgtskrun_rundt, trgtskrun_parent, trgtskrun_transaction, trgtskrun_expire, trgtskrun_data,
            trgmst_id, tskmst_id, jobmst_id, jobrun_id, nodmst_id, nodmst_target, servicemst_id, servicemst_target,
            usrmst_id
            FROM trgtskrun where trgtskrun_id = (select MAX(trgtskrun_id) from trgtskrun)
END
```

Towards any question on design as telling it FROM tablename instead of FROM INSERTED/DELETED those don't allow for copy of text columns of which there are in these tables hence having to do FROM tablename.

Comment: Is `dbo.trgtskrun` the same table as `[Admiral_DEV].[dbo].[trgtskrun]`?

Comment: different tables, different DB.  It's creating a copy of the table but adding some extra columns to add some identification.

Comment: I suspect that you have recursive/nested queries.  It seems very easy when the only difference on the tables is the database where the `create trigger` code would be executed.  This structure would be safer if you had a different table name from the original table.

Comment: ah ok I'll try that out.

Comment: no dice.  i've changed the destination location table to "happycopy" everything modifies in the trigger fine (updated) and enables ok but then the source table stops updating until the trigger is disabled again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a non-answer unless someone can point in the right direction but for people from the future the problem is related to access rights on either the source or destination DB (need to get my DBAs to investigate).  I tried doing the same task with the same application on a DB I have full rights to and the trigger works so either my permissioning on the source or destination DB is causing the break.

UPDATE - further tested and verified.

TRIGGERS and Stored Procedures apparently run as the account that "owns" the database so as soon as I created a similar sql access user in the destination DB as existed in the source DB the trigger worked as designed.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable using this command.

```
ALTER TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME DISABLE;
```

You can enable using this command;

```
ALTER TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME ENABLE;
```